# Migrate MySQL database to PostgreSQL using EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, postgresql-9.6, enterprisedb

I'm trying to convert my MySQL database to PostgreSQL using EnterpriseDB Migration Tool. My setup is as follows:

- Windows 10 x64
- MySQL 5.5.52 Community Edition GPL
- EDB PostgreSQL 9.6.2-2
- EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit 50.0.1

The issue is - it connects successfully to to source MySQL and target PostgreSQL but then fails with the error "unrecognized configuration parameter db_dialect":

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\edb\mtk\bin>runMTK -sourcedbtype mysql s2c_data 

Running EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit (Build 50.0.1) ...  

Source database connectivity info...  
conn=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/s2c_data?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull 
user =s2c_data_user  
password=******  


Target database connectivity info...  
conn =jdbc:edb://localhost:5432/s2c_data  
user =s2c_data_user 
password=******  


Connecting with source MySQL database server...  
Connected to MySQL, version '5.5.52-log'  
Connecting with target EDB Postgres database server...  
Connected to PostgreSQL, version '9.6.2'  

Importing mysql schema s2c_data... 
MTK-17003:Error in copy tables: java.sql.SQLException: com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter: "db_dialect" 
MTK-03000: General Error DB-null: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter: "db_dialect"


One or more schema objects could not be imported during the migration process. Please review the migration output for more details.

Migration logs have been saved to C:\Users\Alex_R\.enterprisedb\migration-toolkit\logs

******************** Migration Summary ********************

Total objects: 0 Successful count: 0 Failed count: 0 Invalid count: 0

*************************************************************

C:\Program Files (x86)\edb\mtk\bin>
```

Anybody faced the same issue? Seems like a bug in EDB MTK but may be I'm missing something. Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [EDB's documentation](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.4/eeguide/Postgres_Plus_Enterprise_Edition_Guide.1.017.html#pID0E0OJQ0HA), this is a parameter of their Postgres PLUS fork of PostgreSQL.

So it looks like this migration tool only works when you migrate to their proprietary version of PostgreSQL, not the standard version.

Comment: Hi, Laurenz, thank you, I think you are right however this is what I don't understand - I did fresh installation of the server and MTK using EDB installer/Stack Builder so they are coming from the same package. May be I was too naive to assume that they should be compatible :)

Comment: I would ask EDB if I were you - it's their product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer to 
[this tool's documentation](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.6/migrate/toc.html).

According to this document, maybe you can try to add one more command line option:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\edb\mtk\bin>runMTK -sourcedbtype mysql -targetdbtype postgresql s2c_data
```

Comment: Tried that and it did not help. I ended up forking DBTransfer on git, fixed all the errors and managed to move my database with all the PK, FK, sequencing, constraints and views. It is generic so anybody wishing to improve it please welcome
https://github.com/abratchik/dbtransfer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - DBTransfer. The original version was pretty old and buggy so I had to fix few things. The source is [here](https://github.com/abratchik/dbtransfer). Feel free to use it for your projects.